# Install package to use with early_command in Ubuntu preseed file

Tags: ubuntu, debian, preseed

I'm trying to make api calls during an ubuntu install using curl, but it always returns the error code 127 which means the command does not exist, this is what it looks like:

```
d-i preseed/early_command string apt-get install curl
d-i preseed/early_command string curl -k http://myapi/get_api
```

Is there a way I can do this for both early and late command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the volume is mounted at this point? This answer seems very relevant to your problem:

https://askubuntu.com/a/90054

The takeaway seems to be that you can use apt-get in the late stage, but not early.

Comment: But you can use `apt-install` -- http://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed

Comment: True, I ended up using wget instead and installing packages after when needed.